# How can I determine when the differed execution will end so that I can load the data in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs, localization, local-storage, deferred-execution

I'm keeping track of the current culture using localisation cookie. I want to load all the messages for the currently selected culture when the application starts and keep them in `localStorage` together with information about their culture, then refresh them only when the selected culture changes (when the value of `'CurrentCulture'` in `localStorage` is different than the one in the cookie).

In my controller, I set 

`$scope.messages = localisationService.messages(localisationMessagesUrl, currentCulture);`

In `localisationService`, I have

```
app.service("localisationService", function ($q, $http, localStorageService) {

        var getCachedMessagesForLanguage = function (localisationMessagesUrl, language) {
            console.log('getCachedMessagesForLanguage');
            var messages = localStorageService.get('Localisation');
            if (!messages || language !== localStorageService.get('Language')) {

                getLocalisationsFromServer(localisationMessagesUrl).then(function (serverMessages) {
                    localStorageService.add('Localisation', messages);
                    localStorageService.add('Language', language);

                });
            }
            return localStorageService.get('Localisation')

        }

        function getLocalisationsFromServer(localisationMessagesUrl) {               
            return $q(function (resolve) {
                $http.get(localisationMessagesUrl)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        resolve(response.data);
                    });
            });
        }         

        return {                
            messages: function (localisationMessagesUrl, language) {
                return getCachedMessagesForLanguage(localisationMessagesUrl, language);
            }
        };

    });
```

`getCachedMessagesForLanguage` returns `undefined` before `getLocalisationsFromServer` finishes, so on the first load I have no messages. If I refresh the page then I get them correctly. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make `getCachedMessagesForLanguage` return a deferred.promise

You can then do ..

```
getCachedMessagesForLanguage(localisationMessagesUrl, 
language).then(function(Localisation) {
  return getLocalisationsFromServer(localisationMessagesUrl)
}).then(function(responseFromGetLocalisationsFromServer) {
  // do your thing here
})
```